# How to manage state for profile pages in React redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, instagram, profile

I know it sounds similar to other questions but its not

I am learning react and wanted to create a sample project to implement whatever i have learnt. I am using redux for state management.
So the app goes as follow.

**APP description**:
User can login to the site and post their pictures there. Other users will be able to view profile and pictures of others too. Its something like Instagram but for web.

My question is how do i manage the data for profile pictures here. Suppose userA visites userB's profile. I can basically fetch userB's profile and its picutres and store it in redux. But what when userA visits some other user's profile. Shall i delete the data for userB from redux store. or shall i maintain this data for all the users that userA visits.

**In nutshell, how do i manage profile and pictures data for multiple users**

Rather than the code i would like to know how the structure and operations would be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, when the component responsible for displaying the profile info is unmounted, you can remove the user B information from the state by dispatching an action and when you visit another user profile you have to set the state with the info of that user by dispatching another action. There is no need to keep the info of all the visited users in your state.

seeing it as a sequence:

1. Component is mounted
2. Call the action creator in componentDidMount or with useEffect if you are using hooks
3. Fetch the data (redux thunk is an option)
4. The action is dispatched
5. Reducer take that action and updates the state
6. Component is re-rendered and shows the data of the visited user
7. Component is unmounted when you leave the page and you can optionally clean the state

Comment: Thanks. Its useful for me. Just like to ask, in this particular case, is it ok to fetch data again and again if the user visits another user multiple time? Apologies. I can't upvote your answer as my rank is below 15

Comment: If you want to improve the user experience you can cache some API calls to avoid the waiting time. Take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/@karolis.sh/caching-api-resources-with-redux-82c7f4bb35d2).